# Zend Framework - New module or just a controller

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm new in Zend Framework. I know this may seem like a stupid question, but i would like to clarify. Creating an application along with a website with ZF, when it's best to create a new module, or just a controller inside a module? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a new module or not is totally based on your requirement.There are few common examples explained below:

1) Generally CMS websites having front end and administrator area, so for that we would prefer to create two modules. `Default` module for the front end (used by end user) and `admin` module used by site administrator only.

2) Another example: if we would like to create a Job Portal website then there will be three type of users be available on the site. Job seeker, Employer and Administrator. So we would prefer to create three modules `applicant`, `employer` and `admin`

Hence when to create a module is depend upon requirement of your application. Also when we require segregation between the features provided to different users, there we generally use modules.

Also refer: [When to use Modules in Zend Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569913/when-to-use-modules-in-zend-framework)

Comment: Well nice. Exactly what i would like to know. Thanks!